# Bold-ing div according to array

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code below consisting 4 row of `divs` what i'm trying to accomplish is using my `arrayBold` array to highlight  the `row div's` that has the same value as the `arrayBold` array in bold. So that all the `sleeping and swimming` will be highlighted in bold.

Is there an easy way to accomplish this any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

```js
  var personArr = [];
var person = {
  ["hobbies"]: ["sleeping", "swimming", "dancing"]
};
var person2 = {
  ["hobbies"]: ["camping", "sleeping", "eating"]
};
var person3 = {
  ["hobbies"]: ["running", "jogging", "sleeping"]
};
var person4 = {
  ["hobbies"]: ["sleeping", "movies", "tv"]
};

var arrayBold = ["sleeping", "swimming"];

personArr.push(person, person2, person3, person4);
console.log(personArr);

var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('line1')[0];
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

personArr.forEach((person, i) => {
  var hobb = document.createElement('div');

  var hobbies = '<div class="wrappingflexbox">';
  $.each(person['hobbies'], function(index) {
    hobbies += '<div class="color-pill hobbies-pill">' + person['hobbies'][index] + '</div>';
  });
  hobbies += '</div>';

  hobb.innerHTML = hobbies;

  frag.appendChild(hobb);
});
parent.appendChild(frag);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

.line1 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.hobbies-pill {
  padding: 3px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: 2px;
}

.color-pill {
  color: black;
  background-color: #E7E7E7;
  cursor: default;
  border: 1px solid #E7E7E7;
}

.wrappingflexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: left;
  margin-left: -3px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
    <body>
        <div class="line1"></div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: it would be nice to see what the `person['hobbies'][index]` looks like and consists of...

Comment: @Anthony is that part not used?

Comment: huh? it would just be good to know what all of the lements in `person['hobbies'][index]` are because it might effect how the code should be written

Comment: check out [my answer!!!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51095654/7543162) it will work for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `includes()` function too:

```js
var personArr = [];
var person = {
  ["hobbies"]: ["sleeping", "swimming", "dancing"]
};
var person2 = {
  ["hobbies"]: ["camping", "sleeping", "eating"]
};
var person3 = {
  ["hobbies"]: ["running", "jogging", "sleeping"]
};
var person4 = {
  ["hobbies"]: ["sleeping", "movies", "tv"]
};

var arrayBold = ["sleeping", "swimming"];

personArr.push(person, person2, person3, person4);
console.log(personArr);

var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('line1')[0];
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

personArr.forEach((person, i) => {
  var hobb = document.createElement('div');

  var hobbies = '<div class="wrappingflexbox">';
  $.each(person['hobbies'], function(index) {
    if (arrayBold.includes(person['hobbies'][index]) == true) {
      hobbies += '<div class="color-pill hobbies-pill" style="font-weight:bold">' + person['hobbies'][index] + '</div>';
    } else {
      hobbies += '<div class="color-pill hobbies-pill">' + person['hobbies'][index] + '</div>';
    }
    
  });
  hobbies += '</div>';

  hobb.innerHTML = hobbies;

  frag.appendChild(hobb);
});
parent.appendChild(frag);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

.line1 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.hobbies-pill {
  padding: 3px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: 2px;
}

.color-pill {
  color: black;
  background-color: #E7E7E7;
  cursor: default;
  border: 1px solid #E7E7E7;
}

.wrappingflexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: left;
  margin-left: -3px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
    <body>
        <div class="line1"></div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 3):

As easy as checking if the current element is in `arrayBold` array

```
$.each(person['hobbies'], function(index) {
    hobbies += '<div class="color-pill hobbies-pill';
    if( arrayBold.indexOf(person['hobbies'][index]) > -1)
        hobbies  += ' bold-text';
    hobbies += '">' + person['hobbies'][index] + '</div>';
});
```

Add css class

```
.bold-text {font-weight: bold;}
```

Comment: May want to add a space between `hobbies-pill` and `bold-text`.

Answer (score 2):

You can add additional class that will make them bold during html construction, I choose to add `emphasis` class if the current word is inside `arrayBold`. That I've checked with `Array.indexOf` function that return **-1** if the item is not exists otherwise its index in the array.

```js
var personArr = [];
var person = {
  ["hobbies"]: ["sleeping", "swimming", "dancing"]
};
var person2 = {
  ["hobbies"]: ["camping", "sleeping", "eating"]
};
var person3 = {
  ["hobbies"]: ["running", "jogging", "sleeping"]
};
var person4 = {
  ["hobbies"]: ["sleeping", "movies", "tv"]
};

var arrayBold = ["sleeping", "swimming"];

personArr.push(person, person2, person3, person4);
console.log(personArr);

var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('line1')[0];
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

personArr.forEach((person, i) => {
  var hobb = document.createElement('div');

  var hobbies = '<div class="wrappingflexbox">';
  $.each(person['hobbies'], function(index) {
    var emphasis = arrayBold.indexOf(person['hobbies'][index]) > -1 ? ' emphasis' : '';
    hobbies += '<div class="color-pill hobbies-pill' + emphasis + '">' + person['hobbies'][index] + '</div>';
  });
  hobbies += '</div>';

  hobb.innerHTML = hobbies;

  frag.appendChild(hobb);
});
parent.appendChild(frag);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

.line1 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.hobbies-pill {
  padding: 3px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: 2px;
}

.color-pill {
  color: black;
  background-color: #E7E7E7;
  cursor: default;
  border: 1px solid #E7E7E7;
}

.color-pill.emphasis {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.wrappingflexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: left;
  margin-left: -3px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="line1"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is your solution:

```
$.each(person['hobbies'], function(index) {
  let hobby = person['hobbies'][index]
  if (arrayBold.includes(hobby)) hobby = '<b>'+hobby+'<b>'
  hobbies += '<div class="color-pill hobbies-pill">' + hobby + '</div>';
});
```

Or another way would be something like this:

```
hobbies += '<div class="color-pill hobbies-pill">' + checkHobby(hobby) + '</div>';

checkHobby = (hobby) => {
  arrayBold.indexOf(hobby) ? '<b>'+hobby+'</b>' : hobby
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ternary condition as `arrayBold.indexOf(hobby) !== -1? '<b>'+hobby+'</b>': hobby` to select the `<b>` conditionally:

```js
var personArr = [];
var person = {
  ["hobbies"]: ["sleeping", "swimming", "dancing"]
};
var person2 = {
  ["hobbies"]: ["camping", "sleeping", "eating"]
};
var person3 = {
  ["hobbies"]: ["running", "jogging", "sleeping"]
};
var person4 = {
  ["hobbies"]: ["sleeping", "movies", "tv"]
};

var arrayBold = ["sleeping", "swimming"];

personArr.push(person, person2, person3, person4);
console.log(personArr);

var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('line1')[0];
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

personArr.forEach((person, i) => {
  var hobb = document.createElement('div');

  var hobbies = '<div class="wrappingflexbox">';
  $.each(person['hobbies'], function(index) {
    var hobby = person['hobbies'][index];
    debugger
    hobbies += '<div class="color-pill hobbies-pill">' + (arrayBold.indexOf(hobby) !== -1? '<b>'+hobby+'</b>': hobby) + '</div>';
  });
  hobbies += '</div>';

  hobb.innerHTML = hobbies;

  frag.appendChild(hobb);
});
parent.appendChild(frag);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

.line1 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.hobbies-pill {
  padding: 3px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: 2px;
}

.color-pill {
  color: black;
  background-color: #E7E7E7;
  cursor: default;
  border: 1px solid #E7E7E7;
}

.wrappingflexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: left;
  margin-left: -3px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
    <body>
        <div class="line1"></div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: @Anthony why? OP asks to make it bold if it exist in bold array.

Comment: because what's in the `person['hobbies'][index]` array might effect how the code should be formed...

Comment: @Anthony did you read the OP's question. Why do you think the content will affect that. That is not the concern in the question.

Comment: @Anthony and your answer is exact copy of mine. With a function call, only a difference.

Comment: oh whoops i thought i was commenting on the OP hahah

Answer (score 1):

```
please refer following fiddle
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rrbairar/pb0ys4au/17/